# Create Expression that accesses a property

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I have a following class:

```
internal class Sensors
{
    public JsonSensor<double> IOPcwFlSpr { get; set; } = new JsonSensor<double>();
 }

internal class JsonSensor<TType> : IJsonSensor
{
    public TType Value { get; set; }
}
```

I want to build an expression that retrieves that property.

```
private static readonly List < PropertyInfo > Properties;

static SensorFactory() {
    Properties = typeof(Json.Sensors).GetProperties().ToList();
}

public void Test(Json.Sensors jsonUpdate) {
    foreach(var property in Properties) {
        var getterMethodInfo = property.GetGetMethod();
        var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(jsonUpdate.GetType(), "x");
        var callExpression = Expression.Call(parameterExpression, getterMethodInfo);

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda < Func < JsonSensor < double >>> (callExpression);
        var r = lambda.Compile().Invoke();
    }
}
```

This throws:

> System.InvalidOperationException : variable 'x' of type 'Sensors'
>   referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Which makes sense, because I never assigned 'x' with an actual object. How do I add the 'parameter object'?

Comment: do you *want* it to be a parameter? or do you want it to be a constant? note: there's **really** no point creating an expression if you're only going to compile it and use it *once* - you might as well just use reflection; is there a reason you want to use expression here? are you planning to cache them later? because if you're going to cache them: it would make sense for the input to be a parameter

Comment: taking a step back; forget about the actual code here; what is the thing that you're *actually trying to achieve* here? if it is just "faster access to the properties" - perhaps something like FastMember might be a simpler option?

Comment: additional note: will the values always be `JsonSensor<double>`? or could they be `JsonSensor<int>` etc? it kinda changes a few things

Comment: @MarcGravell, maybe I am doing it wrong. I have a class with 100+ properties (deserialized via json). Each property represents a sensor in a machine. Every time I receive a new update, I want to update the new sensor values in my own [b]list[/b] of sensor objects. Therefore I thought it would be nice to use reflection to get all properties of the 'json class with 100+ sensor properties', and resolve the property using an expression

Comment: Yes, the JsonSensor is generic. double/int/bool

Comment: OK; that helps; now - in the calling code, when you've got the *value* of each property,  if it can be bool/int/double/etc, what are you going to do there? do you want to treat it as `object`? or...?

Comment: There are stored in another class which implents 'ISensor'. ISensor has a property 'Value' of type string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key when using expression trees like this is to compile it **once** using a parameter (`ParameterExpression`), creating a `Func<Foo,Bar>` that takes your input (`Foo`) and returns whatever you wanted (`Bar`). Then reuse that compiled delegate many times, with different objects.

I can't see *exactly* what you're trying to do, but I'm guessing it would be something like:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;


namespace Json
{
    static class P
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var obj = new Sensors { IOPcwFlSpr = { Value = 42.5 }, Whatever = { Value = 9 } };

            foreach(var pair in SomeUtil.GetSensors(obj))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Name}: {pair.Value}");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Sensors
    {
        public JsonSensor<double> IOPcwFlSpr { get; set; } = new JsonSensor<double>();
        public JsonSensor<int> Whatever { get; set; } = new JsonSensor<int>();
    }

    public interface IJsonSensor
    {
        public string Value { get; }
    }
    public class JsonSensor<TType> : IJsonSensor
    {
        public TType Value { get; set; }
        string IJsonSensor.Value => Convert.ToString(Value);
    }

    public static class SomeUtil
    {
        private static readonly (string name, Func<Sensors, IJsonSensor> accessor)[] s_accessors
            = Array.ConvertAll(
                typeof(Sensors).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public),
                prop => (prop.Name, Compile(prop)));

        public static IEnumerable<(string Name, string Value)> GetSensors(Sensors obj)
        {
            foreach (var acc in s_accessors)
                yield return (acc.name, acc.accessor(obj).Value);
        }
        private static Func<Sensors, IJsonSensor> Compile(PropertyInfo property)
        {
            var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Json.Sensors), "x");
            Expression body = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, property);
            body = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(IJsonSensor));
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Json.Sensors, IJsonSensor>>(body, parameterExpression);
            return lambda.Compile();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One word: impressive. Now I also understand that you had a few questions before. I am doing it wrong. I am storing the expression, while I should be storing the func. The two methods `GetSensors` and `Compile` explain exactly where I went the wrong direction. I will read your answer a couple of times, and then start fixing my code.

Comment: PS: I know we're not supposed to say thank you. But I am googling (the wrong question) for hours now, getting nowhere. So a big fat thanks for getting me on track!

Comment: @bas "thank you" in a comment is fine! I think the guidance on that is just around pre-emptive life stories and gratitudes *in the question*

Comment: Hey Marc, one more question if I may. I though you made a mistake (silly me ;-)). I'd expect the Func defintion to be Func<TResult, TParameter>. Thus I'd expect `Lambda<Func<IJsonSensor, Sensors>>(..,..); ` Can you explain me why the parameter of type `Sensors` is declared as result parameter while it is in fact the argument of the function? It is working perfectly of course, I just don't understand why

Comment: @bas that's because it is `Func<TParameter, TResult>`, not `Func<TResult, TParameter>`

Comment: Oh oops. I would've sworn it was the other way around. That's a good explanation too ;-).

Comment: It works! I'm done! \o/ I am happy. Learned something new and didn't have to write ugly code to get the job done. /bowsdeeply